# Why wireless router can't detect ARP spoofing?

Tags: wireless-networking, arp

This is a very begginer question. We know that ARP protocol isn't secure at all. Computers and routers(/switchs) trust in ARP replies and updates its ARP caches (as far as I know). So, why wireless routers can't detect ARP Spoofing if they only have to check that two or more interfaces in their MAC cache have a same MAC address?

Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Primarily because it isn't a very simple answer to prevent.  Unless the wireless router has additional security software written into it, the router has no way to authenticate you are who you say you are.  It just has to accept the packets it sees and that the machine is who it says it is.

The primary way to prevent arp spoofing is Network Access Control.  Router A is given an account with username/password for machine A.  When Machine A tries to connect, it must give that username/password.  So the router now knows that the mac address for machine A is authorized by the username/password, and Machine A knows that the Router A mac is authenicated.  Hacker Machine B comes along, tries to do a arp spoof, but Router A does not get the authentication token from Hacker Machine A, so treats that as a invalid packet, and drops the arp update.  Same thing happens with Machine A, it gets the arp update from Hacker Machine B, but the packet is not authenticated, so it is dropped.

Without that authentication, there is no way for a standard router to know that Machine A is really Machine A, and not Hacker Machine B.

Now all that extra authenication on every packet takes extra processor power.  In order for the Router to handle that, it has to have better processor, and more memory, which makes it more expensive, and less likely to be chosen when people are looking at price only.

Comment: It wouldn't be on every packet; WPA-Enterprise is not really much heavier than WPA-Personal -- only the initial connection differs.

Comment: thanks for sharing the idea. Although apart from the authentication side, could the router just detect there are two interfaces with the same MAC address and do something about it? why not?

Comment: With WPA (any mode), the "inter-client privacy" option (which has to be enabled on the AP) might make this possible, as each client would have their own encryption key, and the AP could reject packets with mismatching MAC address and key. Other than these keys established during WPA authentication, there is _nothing but_ the MAC address that differentiates between two cards, because that was the whole point of network cards having MAC addresses...

Answer (score 0):

Often in wireless routers LAN ports and the wireless radio share the same tables and are logically combined into one interface. (i.e. the router acts more like a hub when routing traffic between the LAN and the Wireless network.)

As far as an external (WAN) interface is concerned, this is typically a point-to-point interface (one line connecting to another router). Therefore there's only one IP/Mac on the other side of this interface as far as the wireless router is concerned.

Additionally, it is entirely possible that one MAC address has multiple IP addresses, and for load balancing setups it is also possible one IP address is shared between multiple computers.

Comment: In which case, for example a MAC address could have multiple IP addreses?

Comment: @redraw, Simple: You can configure multiple IP addresses on a single NIC.